# How to get cvs log of commits without checking out repo

Tags: cvs

I want to get a list of all commits for a module in cvs without checking that module out. Is this possible? If so how?

I can use the cvs log command like so:

```
cvs log > commitlog.txt
```

but this only appears to work for already checked out module that i'm running the command from. I want to be able to get the log for a module without having to check it out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes.  There is a "rlog" command. It is similar to log except doesn't require checked out code.  In other words, the command is run "remotely."

> rlog [options] [files…]
>
> ```
> Print out history information for modules. See log—Print out log
> ```
>
> information for files.
>
> ```
> -b
>
>     Only list revisions on the default branch. See log options.
> -d dates
>
>     Specify dates (d1<d2 for range, d for latest before). See log
> ```
>
> options.
>       -h
>
> ```
>     Only print header. See log options.
> -l
>
>     Local; run only in current working directory. See Recursive
> ```
>
> behavior.
>       -N
>
> ```
>     Do not list tags. See log options.
> -R
>
>     Only print name of RCS file. See log options.
> -rrevs
>
>     Only list revisions revs. See log options.
> -s states
>
>     Only list revisions with specified states. See log options.
> -t
>
>     Only print header and descriptive text. See log options.
> -wlogins
>
>     Only list revisions checked in by specified logins. See log options.
> ```

Comment: Thanks very much! The link didn't work for me so I had to do a bit of hunting around to get the syntax right. I've already marked your answer correct but I'll also upvote it too if you change your answer to include the command usage/an example &/or fix the link. :)

Comment: Ben,
Odd.  The link still works for me.  But if it doesn't work universally, it is certainly better to have the options included.  So done.

Comment: rlog seem to append ,v the the filename, I thus get the following error when using rlog: 
  `rlog: taxi_rings/RCS/taxi_ring_128.ent,v: No such file or directory`
How can I avoid this behavior?